# Python docstring for descriptors

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython, descriptor, docstring

I am using descriptors to define the registers of an interface class:

```
class Register(object):
    def __init__(self, address, docstring="instance docstring"):
        self.address = address    
        self.__doc__ = docstring

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        return obj.read(self.address)

    def __set__(self, obj, val):
        return obj.write(self.address, val)

class Interface(object):
    r = Register(0x00, docstring="the first register")
```

I wold like the user of ipython to be able to do one of the following:

```
i = Interface()
i.r? #should show the docstring "the first register"
```

or

```
i = Interface()
i.r(  #should show the docstring "the first register" when parentheses are opened
```

However, the docstring is always the one from the int object that obj.read returns, not the specified docstring. Is there a way to show the right docstring in this situation?

If I am not using descriptors but manually define them, it works when the parentheses are open:

```
class Interface(object):
    @property
    def r(self):
        """this docstring will be shown alternatively"""
        return self.read(0x0)

    @r.setter
    def r(self,v):
        """this is the docstring that is shown"""
        self.write(0x0,v)

i = Interface()
i.r( #the right docstring pops up here once i open the bracket
```

If the setter does not define a docstring, the one of the getter is shown when brackets are opened.

Can I somehow get the same behaviour by using descriptors without unreasonable overhead?

My question is somewhat similar to this one, which however gives no satisfactory answer: 
[Creating dynamic docstrings in Python descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045192/creating-dynamic-docstrings-in-python-descriptor)

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues. The first is that the descriptor API also works on classes. So when Ipython tries to get the descriptor from the class, the instance `__get__` logic is getting called, which happens to fail with an `AttributeError`, so the descriptor gets ignored. In your example, if you try to to get the attribute from `Interface`, it raises an error, since it's trying to run on an instance (which is `None` in this case):

```
In [25]: Interface.r
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-dd7a6e721f7e> in <module>
----> 1 Interface.r

<ipython-input-24-7d19c1ba4fe6> in __get__(self, obj, objtype)
      5 
      6     def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
----> 7         return obj.read(self.address)
      8 
      9     def __set__(self, obj, val):

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'
```

The second is that Ipython only uses the descriptor for help if the the descriptor is an instance of `property` (hardcoded). The logic for this is [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/6ddb518ca6ad0b4addfe9ae6e2ac88f4bc12e056/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py#L1615-L1648).

To fix the first issue, you want to return the descriptor itself if it's passed None for obj:

```py
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        ...
```

To fix the second issue, you'd either need to submit a patch to ipython, or subclass from property (much easier, though a bit hacky). Putting these together:

```py
class Register(property):
    def __init__(self, address, docstring="instance docstring"):
        self.address = address    
        self.__doc__ = docstring

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        return obj.read(self.address)

    def __set__(self, obj, val):
        return obj.write(self.address, val)
        

class Interface(object):
    r = Register(0x00, docstring="the first register")

i = Interface()
```

Then in ipython, you get:

```
In [21]: i.r?
Type:        Register
String form: <__main__.Register object at 0x1051203a0>
Docstring:   the first register
```