# Proper way to show the docstring of descriptor with Pylance in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance, python-descriptors

In my project I need to use `user_id` as field in many classes. So I try to concentrate the implementation by using a single **descriptor** instead of duplicating **property**s everywhere.

But there is still a subtle problem, **Pylance in VSCode** won't show the docstring of **descriptor** just like how it works with **property**.

Here is the demo.

```py
class _UserID(object):
    """
    note for test (wont show)
    """

    def __get__(self, obj, _) -> int:
        """
        note for test (wont show)
        """
        return obj._user_id

    def __set__(self, obj, val: int) -> int:
        obj._user_id = int(val) if val else 0
        return val


class UserWithCustomDescriptor(object):
    user_id = _UserID()

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._user_id = 0


class UserWithProperty(object):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._user_id = 0

    @property
    def user_id(self) -> int:
        """
        note for test
        """
        return self._user_id

    @user_id.setter
    def user_id(self, val: int) -> None:
        self._user_id = int(val) if val else 0


if __name__ == "__main__":

    user_prop = UserWithProperty()
    user_prop.user_id = 42
    print(f"{user_prop.__class__.__name__} - {user_prop.user_id}")

    user_desc = UserWithCustomDescriptor()
    user_desc.user_id = 42
    print(f"{user_desc.__class__.__name__} - {user_desc.user_id}")
```

If you hover your mouse over the `user_prop.user_id`, the docstring will be showed like this:

[image: user_prop]

while the `user_desc.user_id` won't show the docstring:

[image: user_desc]

I found a similar question here [python-docstring-for-descriptors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37255109/python-docstring-for-descriptors), but the answer below could not slove this problem.

And I also tried to find solution in [python-doc#properties](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#properties). It seems property will return an instance carrying docstring instead of a direct value. Maybe it's close to the final answer but I'm already stuck in this step for several hours.

Comment: And does vscode show "variable docstrings"? With `#:` or regular `"""..."""` right below variable definition (`user_id = _UserID()`). This is what sphinx uses to document variables, maybe vscode can handle it too. Don't have vscode installed, so can't check, unfortunately.

Comment: @SUTerliakov `#:` will be ignored by Pylance if it belongs to a `ClassVar`

Comment: Interesting, and when is it not ignored? Module attributes only? Or everything except class variables annotated with `ClassVar` (it'd be very odd)?

Comment: @SUTerliakov I‘ve just checked, the `#:` will always be ignored by Pylance. The previous reply is just a mistake of my memory.

Comment: I can get [intellisense](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49FCp.png) in my [vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHiRQ.png) and try to reinstall the pylance extension